# difference between using extern and using a getter?

Tags: c++

I have a camera class that sets up two variables - a projection and a view matrix. I could either make these extern and include the header in anything I wanted to have access to the variables, or I could make a getter for them / pass references for these variables to anything that needed them. Is this simply a case of preference or are there real benefits to doing it a particular way?

Comment: By extern, do you mean public, are have you really written a class to manage two global variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A getter has the advantage of not letting external code write in your variable (eg a pointer array can't be incremented).

Otherwise, it's functionally the same, especially if it's for your own use.

Comment: oh ok, awesome, thanks. And I am right in thinking that even if something's extern, you still need to actually #include the file it's in to use it right?

Comment: Yes, the other files need to know the variables exist. You need to declare the variables as `extern` in your header, and as normal variables (without extern) where you want to implement this variable.

Answer (score 1):

It is more a question of encapsulation. If your camera class is the only holder of these two matrices, it would be wise to make them available via getters and not with public attributes.

This will, for example, allow you to subclass your camera and create other methods for your view and projection matrices.